# How to click on a label in a listBox and have text show up in multiple textBoxs

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I am designing a planner and I'm having in issue when I click on my add task button. Once I click on it, my program crashes and this error is displayed:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.'"

Where would I find the incorrect syntax?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace InfoHub
{
    public partial class Planner : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\epoch\source\repos\InfoHub\InfoHub\planner.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        public Planner()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Planner_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void addTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into table values('" + textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";
            textBox7.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with labels, planners or list boxes and everything to do with using SQL Parameters every time, all the time.  Forever.

Comment: i am confused on what you mean by this could, where would I start on working with the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You are using sql insert command incorrectly:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into table values('" + textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"')";
```

table is sql keyword and it is not treated as table name. Try adding writing it as 'table' to inform sql that 'table' is name of particular table and not keyword:

```
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into 'table' values('" + textBox3.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox6.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"')";
```

generally it is good practice to always write names in ' '.

Comment: adding with those adjustments to it now shows that there is a syntax error near 'table'. i think that my table my be set up wrong or not properly linked.